# How to remove the date under the draftmode in AEA document class?

Tags: document-classes, class-options, draft

When using the `AEA` document class in `draftmode`, there is a date command that appears with the `\maketitle`.  Does anyone know how to eliminate it?  When using `\date{}` as would usually work, the date is eliminated, however, there seems to be a date name which just says "Draft:" which still remains.  I then tried using `\renewcommand{\date}{}` and `\renewcommand{\datename}{}`, both of these do not seem to eliminate "Draft:" which still remains when using `\date{}`.

This problem seems specific to using the `AEA` document class and I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>The easiest</strike>One way is to edit the `aea.cls` file: search for "Draft:", comment out the line:

```
\def\draftDate{\if@draftmode\vspace{12pt}\begin{center}Draft: \@date\end{center}\par
```

and replace it with:

```
\def\draftDate{\if@draftmode\vspace{12pt}\begin{center}Draft\end{center}\par
```

This will permanently remove the date though. You need to uncomment the line if you want it back.

Comment: What about removing it using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)? `\usepackage{etoolbox} \makeatletter \patchcmd{\draftDate}{Draft: \@date}{Draft}{}{} \makeatother`

Comment: @Werner: Looks better. I also tried to add an `if` statement to check if `\date` was defined as blank (as the OP did with `\date{}`), but didn't work.

Comment: jak I did what you said, but instead of overwriting the original file, I made a new one and saved it in a new folder and thus made a new class which I now call upon in the document.  Thank you, this did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

In [`AEA.cls`](https://www.aeaweb.org/aer/submissions.php), this is governed by the macro `\draftDate`. Either redefine `\draftDate` in your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\draftDate}{\vspace{12pt} Draft}
```

or patch `\maketitle` (or `\draftDate`) to only insert what you want:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\draftDate}{\vspace{12pt} Draft}{}{}
\makeatother
```

[image]

```
% https://www.aeaweb.org/aer/submissions.php
\documentclass[AEJ,draftmode]{AEA}

\renewcommand{\draftDate}{\vspace{12pt} Draft}

...
```

Comment: I guess the `\renewcommand` option is the easiest then!